# How do we repair a hole in our basement foundation wall and the floor?

Tags: hole-repair

Our house was built in 1924. There's a hole in the foundation wall that we need to patch up.

I know we can replace the bricks but what do we fill in the hole with?

Directly over it upstairs (in the front room) is an old wood fireplace that has been replaced with an electronic heater the last owner added to the house.[image]

Comment: Just wondering if that was a clean out for chimney?  What is on other side of wall?

Comment: If you are sure it services no purpose, why not just patch a brick in? What is the stuff in front of the ww?

Answer (score 1):

It is to remove ashes from the fireplace that is above it. So there will be a shaft up to the fireplace. I would  only fill in the hole shown and not fill the shaft.

Comment: Hi Thanks. I was thinking of blocking the hole then bricking it up. The fireplace is not used anymore. The chimney has a grate over it so hopefully nothing can ever come down it. They left a very large mirror in front of it when they moved out. More likely just hiding it until we found it. Appreciate your response.

Comment: @ValentineFamily if you'll take the [tour], you'll note that the appropriate way to say "thanks" is to click the up vote button next to _every_ answer that was helpful to you, then to click the check mark next to the answer that helped you the _most__.